# How to calculate ΔSST change in time series climate dataset

Tags: climate, temperature, python

I have monthly SST data (21 years = 252 months) and now I am wondering to figure out ΔSST in python.
Basically I am unable to understand the Δ term meaning as shown in below equation:

[image]

I am able to calculate the first part of the equation (i.e., partial change) using statsmodel.OLS regression slope, but stuck to multiply that slope value with ΔSST.